how to set Dynamic add content in Compression type in copy activity
I created the dynamic dataset and linker service. In copy activity i used that dynamic dataset and want to pass parameter in copy activity or use Compression type option as parameter/Dynamic, when i click on Compression type there is drop down menu and found option of add dynamic add content, but unable how to add or use this option  . 
I implement the answer in azure and found some issue , can you please have a look.
first i created two parameters

After parameters i edit the json as well, you can review it


and pass the parameter as string

But the. main issue is that i am unable to get these parameters into datasets You can check this picture.


Can you add images of your pipeline for better understanding

images has been shared i post , thank you for your support and consideration @Prakit Lad

@JunaidBilal, you can use dynamic expression by editing the dataset json. please check the below answer.

Ya, @RakeshGovindula.
Thank you for to all community members, i am doing POC on this answer and will share my result with all of you soon.

@JunaidBilal, I have added the update for the delimited text file as well, Is it working?

i implemented the answer and can not able to get the parameters into dataset , screenshot is attached , please review and thank you for your suggestion @RakeshGovindula

Re-check my Update section, for the delimited text dataset you need to edit the dataset JSON for the compressionCodec key. In your image, you did for the compression which is not required in case of delimited text dataset and the compressionCodec is null in your JSON. compression key editing is required when you use Binary dataset.

i. would like to thank you for your support and time because your reply and provided solution has  solved my problem.
Thank you @RakeshGovindula

This behavior might be a bug in the datasets of ADF. You can achieve your requirement by changing the dataset JSON as shown below.
First create the required dataset parameters.

Now, go to the dataset JSON by clicking on the icon {} at the top right corner of the dataset and edit the JSON to add the dynamic content expression.
Here, I have used Binary dataset, and I have edited the dataset JSON as shown below.
{
    "name": "Binary_source_compression",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "ADLS_nov20th_test",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "comp_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "comp_level": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": "mainzip.zip",
                "fileSystem": "zipsinputcon"
            },
            "compression": {
                "type": {
                    "value": "@dataset().comp_type",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "level": {
                    "value": "@dataset().comp_level",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Click on ok and now it will show the dynamic expression for these properties at the dataset level.

Give the required values to these parameters in the copy activity.

Run the pipeline and it will give the desired results.
UPDATE:
For the csv file, you can edit the dataset JSON as below.
        "compressionCodec": {
                "value": "@dataset().comp",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "compressionLevel": {
                "value": "@dataset().comp_level",
                "type": "Expression"
            }


